# Django- How to determine field types in ModelForm init?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-widget

I want to change widget for all BooleanField's in model to Yes/No radio buttons, thought it will be simple:

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    logger.debug("%s -------" % self.__class__.__name__)
    super(FormClass,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    for field in self.fields:
        logger.debug("field of type %s" % type(field))
        if type(field) == BooleanField:
            logger.debug('YES BOOLEAN')
            field.widget = RadioSelect(choices=self.TN_CHOICES)
```

but it does nothing. In debug log I see every field type is `str`. How to determine associated model field type?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is that a form's `fields` attribute appears to act like a dict. Iterating over that gives you only the fieldnames, which are strings.

Instead try

```
for name, field in self.fields.items():
    ...
```

This will bind the `field` variable to the actual field.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks holdenweb - your solution is working. In the meantime I figured out my own alternative

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FormClass,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
     for field_name in self.fields:
         if type(self.fields[field_name])==BooleanField:
             self.fields[field_name].widget = RadioSelect(choices=self.YN_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.fields` is a dictionary. When you iterate through a dictionary, you get the *keys*, which here are strings. You could iterate through `self.fields.values()` to fix this.

However there is a much simpler way, which is to use the [`widgets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) attribute in the modelform's Meta class.

Comment: it's not the simple way if you got lot of different types of fields in long form...

Answer (score 0):

Using @Lord_JABA answer, I personally used the following code to check the type of the form field (here I check for DateField):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FormClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  
    

    for name, field in self.fields.items():
        str_representation = str(field)
        if "DateField" in str_representation:
            # do something if the field is a DateField
```